# Yii2 on button click pass id to render partial with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

So on my index page I list all the rows and some fields within my model on button click I want a modal to popup with all the data from the row that the button corresponds to.

So on button click I want the ajax call to render a partial view this will require me to pass the id of the item when doing the ajax call.

```
            <div class="col-sm-3 small-item">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">
                    <img src="<?= $model->featured_img; ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h4><?= $model->title; ?></h4>
                        <p><?= $model->sub_title; ?></p>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btnsolid-sm btn-black">View Full Data</a> //this is the button that when clicked the popup should appear with all the related data
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add another attribute to the button holding the id of the record. Let's say `data-id="<?= $model->id ?>"`

So when you click the button in JS you can retrieve the id with

```
var record_id = $(this).data('id');
```

and then use it as data for the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my/url/bla',
    data: {
        id: record_id
    },
    success: function() {
        // magic here 
    } 
});
```